# Bootstrap modal view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal in my code but when **I open modal it not display in a proper way**. 
Please tell me where is my code wrong?
I attach my html, css with screen-shot file below:

This my code on codepen:
[`Bootstrap modal view`](https://codepen.io/arpita1030/pen/jgvrJQ)

This current look:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

Comment: Please provide us the minimal html/css code, where this behavior occurs, not the whole page with navbar, unnecessary css, ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please check code now i remove unnecessary code @PavelTřupek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't any parent div to `modal` div. It should be under `body` tag

See this [working demo](https://codepen.io/kareemda/pen/qeMaKP)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the modal inside any div which is having fixed width or position absolute or fixed.
Use the modal code in the last like after the footer. And also check the parent **z-index** value.